# How to use MongoDB documents in latex template?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pdflatex

I am creating a `pdf` file from `latex` template, i have successfully compiled template file(`.tex`) to `pdf` with static value of template now i am going to use my data which are got from `mongo`, but i didn't understand how to put it in `latex` template.
If you have idea then share it.
Here my code

```
var sys   = require('sys'),
spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
pdflatex    = spawn('pdflatex', ['', '','cv_11.tex']);
pdflatex.on('exit', function (code) {
console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
```

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/index.html

Comment: thanx @JohnnyHK i have string value from database, problem to append it in latex template.